# How to troubleshoot a permanently blinking green light on a Pi3b?

Tags: pi-3, hdmi, bluetooth, archlinux, arm

The green light on a Pi3b is blinking permanently, even after bootup. It outputs two flashes at a time for as long as the power is on. Is this normal? If not, how do I troubleshoot this?

**Background**

On a clean install of Arch Linux ARMv8, a strange hdmi/bluetooth related error caused my Pi3b to crash during the middle of a full system update `pacman -Syu`. It was completely frozen to the extent that a forced shutdown was the only option. The only documentation of this error is the attached image.

[image: hdmi_bluetooth_error]

After restarting the device, everything seemed okay, meaning that the boot process completed and the user could login and run commands. However, as mentioned, the device went into a permanent cycle of green light flashes, where the green light blinks twice as long as the power is on.

It made sense to completely wipe the SD card with `dd` and start over. However, even after a fresh reinstall, the flashing green light is still present, implying that something deep in the hardware has been affected.

**Sequence of troubleshooting attempts**

Several journalctl logs were ran, however, to the untrained eye, they do not seem to reveal any explicit information about the state of the device.

Display current boot log

```
journalctl -b -n 125

-- Logs begin at Thu 2018-07-05 19:44:53 UTC, end at Thu 2018-08-23 03:50:31 UTC. --
Aug 22 05:03:30 alarm haveged[325]: haveged: ver: 1.9.4; arch: generic; vend: ; build: (gcc 8.2.0 CTV); collect: 128K
Aug 22 05:03:30 alarm haveged[325]: haveged: cpu: (VC); data: 16K (D); inst: 16K (D); idx: 11/40; sz: 15528/64688
Aug 22 05:03:30 alarm haveged[325]: haveged: tot tests(BA8): A:1/1 B:1/1 continuous tests(B):  last entropy estimate 8.00098
Aug 22 05:03:30 alarm haveged[325]: haveged: fills: 0, generated: 0
Aug 22 05:03:32 alarm systemd-networkd[322]: eth0: Gained IPv6LL
Aug 22 05:03:32 alarm systemd-timesyncd[321]: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection.
Aug 22 05:03:33 alarm systemd-networkd[322]: eth0: DHCPv4 address 192.168.1.113/24 via 192.168.1.1
Aug 22 05:03:33 alarm dbus-daemon[328]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.0' (uid=63822 pid=322 comm="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-networkd ")
Aug 22 05:03:33 alarm systemd-timesyncd[321]: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection.
Aug 22 05:03:33 alarm systemd-timesyncd[321]: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection.
Aug 22 05:03:33 alarm systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
Aug 22 05:03:33 alarm systemd-networkd[322]: eth0: DHCPv6 address fd3c:7b6f:5f64::57f/128 timeout preferred -1 valid -1
Aug 22 05:03:33 alarm systemd-networkd[322]: eth0: DHCPv6 address 2602:306:c58e:24e9::57f/128 timeout preferred 565038 valid 2552238
Aug 22 05:03:33 alarm dbus-daemon[328]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Aug 22 05:03:33 alarm systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
Aug 22 05:03:34 alarm systemd-networkd[322]: eth0: Configured
Aug 22 05:03:34 alarm systemd-timesyncd[321]: Network configuration changed, trying to establish connection.
Aug 22 05:03:38 alarm kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: failed to write update baudrate (-110)
Aug 22 05:03:38 alarm kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to set baudrate
Aug 22 05:03:38 alarm kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 94
Aug 22 05:03:38 alarm kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x2e
Aug 22 05:03:38 alarm kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43430A1
Aug 22 05:03:38 alarm kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43430A1 (001.002.009) build 0000
Aug 22 05:03:42 alarm kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43430A1 (001.002.009) build 0360
Aug 22 05:03:45 alarm login[341]: pam_unix(login:session): session opened for user alarm by LOGIN(uid=0)
Aug 22 05:03:45 alarm systemd[1]: Created slice User Slice of UID 1000.
Aug 22 05:03:45 alarm systemd[1]: Created slice system-user\x2druntime\x2ddir.slice.
Aug 22 05:03:45 alarm systemd[1]: Started /run/user/1000 mount wrapper.
Aug 22 05:03:45 alarm systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 1000...
Aug 22 05:03:45 alarm systemd-logind[329]: New session c1 of user alarm.
Aug 22 05:03:45 alarm systemd[1]: Started Session c1 of user alarm.
Aug 22 05:03:45 alarm systemd[346]: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user alarm by (uid=0)
Aug 22 05:03:45 alarm systemd[346]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (access for web browsers).
Aug 22 05:03:45 alarm systemd[346]: Starting D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.
Aug 22 05:03:45 alarm login[341]: LOGIN ON tty1 BY alarm
Aug 22 05:03:45 alarm systemd[346]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache.
Aug 22 05:03:45 alarm systemd[346]: Reached target Paths.
Aug 22 05:03:45 alarm systemd[346]: Reached target Timers.
Aug 22 05:03:45 alarm systemd[346]: Listening on p11-kit server.
Aug 22 05:03:45 alarm systemd[346]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent (ssh-agent emulation).
Aug 22 05:03:45 alarm systemd[346]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (restricted).
Aug 22 05:03:45 alarm systemd[346]: Listening on GnuPG network certificate management daemon.
Aug 22 05:03:45 alarm systemd[346]: Listening on D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.
Aug 22 05:03:45 alarm systemd[346]: Reached target Sockets.
Aug 22 05:03:45 alarm systemd[346]: Reached target Basic System.
Aug 22 05:03:45 alarm systemd[346]: Reached target Default.
Aug 22 05:03:45 alarm systemd[346]: Startup finished in 247ms.
Aug 22 05:03:45 alarm systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 1000.
Aug 23 03:26:24 alarm systemd-timesyncd[321]: Synchronized to time server [2600:3c00::2:b401]:123 (2.arch.pool.ntp.org).
Aug 23 03:26:25 alarm systemd[1]: Starting Rotate log files...
Aug 23 03:26:25 alarm systemd[1]: Starting Update man-db cache...
Aug 23 03:26:25 alarm systemd[1]: Started Verify integrity of password and group files.
Aug 23 03:26:25 alarm systemd[1]: Started Rotate log files.
Aug 23 03:26:28 alarm mandb[365]: Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man...
Aug 23 03:26:28 alarm mandb[365]: Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man...
Aug 23 03:26:28 alarm mandb[365]: Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/fr...
Aug 23 03:26:28 alarm mandb[365]: Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/fr...
Aug 23 03:26:28 alarm mandb[365]: Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/pt_BR...
Aug 23 03:26:28 alarm mandb[365]: Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/pt_BR...
Aug 23 03:26:28 alarm mandb[365]: Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/fr.UTF-8...
Aug 23 03:26:28 alarm mandb[365]: Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/fr.UTF-8...
Aug 23 03:26:28 alarm mandb[365]: Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/ko...
Aug 23 03:26:28 alarm mandb[365]: Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/ko...
Aug 23 03:26:28 alarm mandb[365]: Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/id...
Aug 23 03:26:28 alarm mandb[365]: Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/id...
Aug 23 03:26:28 alarm mandb[365]: Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/cs...
Aug 23 03:26:28 alarm mandb[365]: Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/cs...
Aug 23 03:26:28 alarm mandb[365]: Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/hu...
Aug 23 03:26:28 alarm mandb[365]: Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/hu...
Aug 23 03:26:28 alarm mandb[365]: Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/sv...
Aug 23 03:26:28 alarm mandb[365]: Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/sv...
Aug 23 03:26:28 alarm mandb[365]: Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/da...
Aug 23 03:26:28 alarm mandb[365]: Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/da...
Aug 23 03:26:28 alarm mandb[365]: Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/es...
Aug 23 03:26:28 alarm mandb[365]: Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/es...
Aug 23 03:26:28 alarm mandb[365]: Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/it...
Aug 23 03:26:28 alarm mandb[365]: Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/it...
Aug 23 03:26:28 alarm mandb[365]: Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/pl...
Aug 23 03:26:28 alarm mandb[365]: Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/pl...
Aug 23 03:26:28 alarm mandb[365]: Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/zh_CN...
Aug 23 03:26:28 alarm mandb[365]: Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/zh_CN...
Aug 23 03:26:28 alarm mandb[365]: Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/sr...
Aug 23 03:26:28 alarm mandb[365]: Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/sr...
Aug 23 03:26:28 alarm mandb[365]: Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/zh_TW...
Aug 23 03:26:28 alarm mandb[365]: Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/zh_TW...
Aug 23 03:26:28 alarm mandb[365]: Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/de...
Aug 23 03:26:28 alarm mandb[365]: Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/de...
Aug 23 03:26:28 alarm mandb[365]: Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/fr.ISO8859-1...
Aug 23 03:26:28 alarm mandb[365]: Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/fr.ISO8859-1...
Aug 23 03:26:28 alarm mandb[365]: Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/tr...
Aug 23 03:26:28 alarm mandb[365]: Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/tr...
Aug 23 03:26:28 alarm mandb[365]: Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/ru...
Aug 23 03:26:28 alarm mandb[365]: Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/ru...
Aug 23 03:26:28 alarm mandb[365]: Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/ja...
Aug 23 03:26:28 alarm mandb[365]: Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/ja...
Aug 23 03:26:28 alarm mandb[365]: Purging old database entries in /usr/share/man/nl...
Aug 23 03:26:28 alarm mandb[365]: Processing manual pages under /usr/share/man/nl...
Aug 23 03:26:28 alarm mandb[365]: Processing manual pages under /usr/local/man...
Aug 23 03:26:28 alarm mandb[365]: 0 man subdirectories contained newer manual pages.
Aug 23 03:26:28 alarm mandb[365]: 0 manual pages were added.
Aug 23 03:26:28 alarm mandb[365]: 0 stray cats were added.
Aug 23 03:26:28 alarm mandb[365]: 16 old database entries were purged.
Aug 23 03:26:28 alarm systemd[1]: Started Update man-db cache.
Aug 23 03:41:16 alarm systemd[1]: Starting Cleanup of Temporary Directories...
Aug 23 03:41:16 alarm systemd[1]: Started Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
Aug 23 03:50:09 alarm sshd[568]: Connection closed by authenticating user alarm 192.168.1.154 port 44152 [preauth]
Aug 23 03:50:10 alarm sshd[571]: Connection closed by authenticating user alarm 192.168.1.154 port 44154 [preauth]
Aug 23 03:50:14 alarm sshd[573]: Accepted password for alarm from 192.168.1.154 port 44156 ssh2
Aug 23 03:50:14 alarm sshd[573]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user alarm by (uid=0)
Aug 23 03:50:14 alarm systemd-logind[329]: New session c2 of user alarm.
Aug 23 03:50:14 alarm systemd[1]: Started Session c2 of user alarm.
Aug 23 03:50:14 alarm sshd[575]: Received disconnect from 192.168.1.154 port 44156:11: disconnected by user
Aug 23 03:50:14 alarm sshd[575]: Disconnected from user alarm 192.168.1.154 port 44156
Aug 23 03:50:14 alarm sshd[573]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user alarm
Aug 23 03:50:14 alarm systemd-logind[329]: Session c2 logged out. Waiting for processes to exit.
Aug 23 03:50:14 alarm systemd-logind[329]: Removed session c2.
Aug 23 03:50:26 alarm sshd[579]: Accepted password for alarm from 192.168.1.154 port 44158 ssh2
Aug 23 03:50:26 alarm sshd[579]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user alarm by (uid=0)
Aug 23 03:50:26 alarm systemd-logind[329]: New session c3 of user alarm.
Aug 23 03:50:26 alarm systemd[1]: Started Session c3 of user alarm.
Aug 23 03:50:31 alarm sshd[581]: Received disconnect from 192.168.1.154 port 44158:11: disconnected by user
Aug 23 03:50:31 alarm sshd[581]: Disconnected from user alarm 192.168.1.154 port 44158
Aug 23 03:50:31 alarm sshd[579]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user alarm
Aug 23 03:50:31 alarm systemd-logind[329]: Session c3 logged out. Waiting for processes to exit.
Aug 23 03:50:31 alarm systemd-logind[329]: Removed session c3.
```

Display kernel messages log

```
journalctl -k -n 125

-- Logs begin at Thu 2018-07-05 19:44:53 UTC, end at Thu 2018-08-23 03:50:31 UTC. --
Jul 05 19:44:53 alarm kernel: Key type encrypted registered
Jul 05 19:44:53 alarm kernel: mmcblk0: mmc0:aaaa SC32G 29.7 GiB 
Jul 05 19:44:53 alarm kernel: 3f201000.serial: ttyAMA0 at MMIO 0x3f201000 (irq = 66, base_baud = 0) is a PL011 rev2
Jul 05 19:44:53 alarm kernel: serial serial0: tty port ttyAMA0 registered
Jul 05 19:44:53 alarm kernel: raspberrypi-firmware soc:firmware: Attached to firmware from 2018-08-16 17:30
Jul 05 19:44:53 alarm kernel: random: fast init done
Jul 05 19:44:53 alarm kernel: vchiq: vchiq_init_state: slot_zero = (____ptrval____), is_master = 0
Jul 05 19:44:53 alarm kernel:  mmcblk0: p1 p2
Jul 05 19:44:53 alarm kernel: dwc2 3f980000.usb: 3f980000.usb supply vusb_d not found, using dummy regulator
Jul 05 19:44:53 alarm kernel: dwc2 3f980000.usb: 3f980000.usb supply vusb_a not found, using dummy regulator
Jul 05 19:44:53 alarm kernel: mmc1: new high speed SDIO card at address 0001
Jul 05 19:44:53 alarm kernel: dwc2 3f980000.usb: dwc2_check_params: Invalid parameter lpm=1
Jul 05 19:44:53 alarm kernel: dwc2 3f980000.usb: dwc2_check_params: Invalid parameter lpm_clock_gating=1
Jul 05 19:44:53 alarm kernel: dwc2 3f980000.usb: dwc2_check_params: Invalid parameter besl=1
Jul 05 19:44:53 alarm kernel: dwc2 3f980000.usb: dwc2_check_params: Invalid parameter hird_threshold_en=1
Jul 05 19:44:53 alarm kernel: dwc2 3f980000.usb: DWC OTG Controller
Jul 05 19:44:53 alarm kernel: dwc2 3f980000.usb: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
Jul 05 19:44:53 alarm kernel: dwc2 3f980000.usb: irq 41, io mem 0x3f980000
Jul 05 19:44:53 alarm kernel: usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 4.18
Jul 05 19:44:53 alarm kernel: usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
Jul 05 19:44:53 alarm kernel: usb usb1: Product: DWC OTG Controller
Jul 05 19:44:53 alarm kernel: usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 4.18.2-1-ARCH dwc2_hsotg
Jul 05 19:44:53 alarm kernel: usb usb1: SerialNumber: 3f980000.usb
Jul 05 19:44:53 alarm kernel: hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
Jul 05 19:44:53 alarm kernel: hub 1-0:1.0: 1 port detected
Jul 05 19:44:53 alarm kernel: hctosys: unable to open rtc device (rtc0)
Jul 05 19:44:53 alarm kernel: ALSA device list:
Jul 05 19:44:53 alarm kernel:   No soundcards found.
Jul 05 19:44:53 alarm kernel: Freeing unused kernel memory: 1600K
Jul 05 19:44:53 alarm kernel: usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using dwc2
Jul 05 19:44:53 alarm kernel: usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=9514, bcdDevice= 2.00
Jul 05 19:44:53 alarm kernel: usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
Jul 05 19:44:53 alarm kernel: hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
Jul 05 19:44:53 alarm kernel: hub 1-1:1.0: 5 ports detected
Jul 05 19:44:53 alarm kernel: usb 1-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using dwc2
Jul 05 19:44:53 alarm kernel: usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=ec00, bcdDevice= 2.00
Jul 05 19:44:53 alarm kernel: usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
Jul 05 19:44:53 alarm kernel: EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
Jul 05 19:44:53 alarm kernel: usb 1-1.5: new full-speed USB device number 4 using dwc2
Jul 05 19:44:53 alarm systemd[1]: System time before build time, advancing clock.
Jul 05 19:44:53 alarm kernel: usb 1-1.5: New USB device found, idVendor=062a, idProduct=4101, bcdDevice= 3.21
Jul 05 19:44:53 alarm kernel: usb 1-1.5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Jul 05 19:44:53 alarm kernel: usb 1-1.5: Product: 2.4G Keyboard Mouse
Jul 05 19:44:53 alarm kernel: usb 1-1.5: Manufacturer: MOSART Semi.
Jul 05 19:44:53 alarm kernel: input: MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse as /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.0/0003:062A:4101.0001/input/input0
Jul 05 19:44:53 alarm systemd[1]: systemd 239 running in system mode. (+PAM -AUDIT -SELINUX -IMA -APPARMOR +SMACK -SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD -IDN2 +IDN +PCRE2 default-hierarchy=hybrid)
Jul 05 19:44:53 alarm kernel: hid-generic 0003:062A:4101.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse] on usb-3f980000.usb-1.5/input0
Jul 05 19:44:53 alarm systemd[1]: Detected architecture arm64.
Jul 05 19:44:53 alarm kernel: input: MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse Mouse as /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.1/0003:062A:4101.0002/input/input1
Jul 05 19:44:53 alarm kernel: input: MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse Consumer Control as /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.1/0003:062A:4101.0002/input/input2
Jul 05 19:44:53 alarm systemd[1]: Set hostname to <alarm>.
Jul 05 19:44:53 alarm kernel: input: MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse System Control as /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.1/0003:062A:4101.0002/input/input3
Jul 05 19:44:53 alarm kernel: input: MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse as /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.1/0003:062A:4101.0002/input/input4
Jul 05 19:44:53 alarm kernel: hid-generic 0003:062A:4101.0002: input,hiddev96,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [MOSART Semi. 2.4G Keyboard Mouse] on usb-3f980000.usb-1.5/input1
Jul 05 19:44:53 alarm kernel: random: crng init done
Jul 05 19:44:53 alarm systemd[1]: Created slice system-getty.slice.
Jul 05 19:44:53 alarm systemd[1]: Set up automount Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System Automount Point.
Jul 05 19:44:53 alarm systemd[1]: Created slice User and Session Slice.
Jul 05 19:44:53 alarm systemd[1]: Reached target Slices.
Jul 05 19:44:53 alarm systemd[1]: Listening on Process Core Dump Socket.
Jul 05 19:44:53 alarm systemd[1]: Listening on LVM2 metadata daemon socket.
Jul 05 19:44:53 alarm systemd[1]: Listening on Device-mapper event daemon FIFOs.
Jul 05 19:44:54 alarm kernel: bcm2835-wdt 3f100000.watchdog: Broadcom BCM2835 watchdog timer
Jul 05 19:44:54 alarm kernel: i2c-bcm2835 3f805000.i2c: Could not read clock-frequency property
Jul 05 19:44:54 alarm kernel: Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
Jul 05 19:44:54 alarm kernel: NET: Registered protocol family 31
Jul 05 19:44:54 alarm kernel: Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
Jul 05 19:44:54 alarm kernel: Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
Jul 05 19:44:54 alarm kernel: Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
Jul 05 19:44:54 alarm kernel: Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
Jul 05 19:44:54 alarm kernel: cfg80211: Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates for regulatory database
Jul 05 19:44:54 alarm kernel: smsc95xx v1.0.6
Jul 05 19:44:55 alarm kernel: Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
Jul 05 19:44:55 alarm kernel: Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
Jul 05 19:44:55 alarm kernel: Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCSP registered
Jul 05 19:44:55 alarm kernel: Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol LL registered
Jul 05 19:44:55 alarm kernel: Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol ATH3K registered
Jul 05 19:44:55 alarm kernel: Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
Jul 05 19:44:55 alarm kernel: Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Intel registered
Jul 05 19:44:55 alarm kernel: Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Broadcom registered
Jul 05 19:44:55 alarm kernel: uart-pl011 3f201000.serial: no DMA platform data
Jul 05 19:44:55 alarm kernel: Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol QCA registered
Jul 05 19:44:55 alarm kernel: Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Marvell registered
Jul 05 19:44:55 alarm kernel: smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: register 'smsc95xx' at usb-3f980000.usb-1.1, smsc95xx USB 2.0 Ethernet, b8:27:eb:b7:46:98
Jul 05 19:44:55 alarm kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver smsc95xx
Jul 05 19:44:55 alarm kernel: cfg80211: Loaded X.509 cert 'sforshee: 00b28ddf47aef9cea7'
Jul 05 19:44:55 alarm kernel: Registered IR keymap rc-cec
Jul 05 19:44:55 alarm kernel: rc rc0: RC for vc4 as /devices/platform/soc/3f902000.hdmi/rc/rc0
Jul 05 19:44:55 alarm kernel: input: RC for vc4 as /devices/platform/soc/3f902000.hdmi/rc/rc0/input6
Jul 05 19:44:55 alarm kernel: vc4_hdmi 3f902000.hdmi: ASoC: Failed to create component debugfs directory
Jul 05 19:44:55 alarm kernel: brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac43430-sdio for chip BCM43430/1
Jul 05 19:44:55 alarm kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver brcmfmac
Jul 05 19:44:55 alarm kernel: vc4_hdmi 3f902000.hdmi: vc4-hdmi-hifi <-> 3f902000.hdmi mapping ok
Jul 05 19:44:55 alarm kernel: vc4_hdmi 3f902000.hdmi: ASoC: no DMI vendor name!
Jul 05 19:44:55 alarm kernel: vc4-drm soc:gpu: bound 3f902000.hdmi (ops vc4_hdmi_ops [vc4])
Jul 05 19:44:55 alarm kernel: vc4-drm soc:gpu: bound 3f806000.vec (ops vc4_vec_ops [vc4])
Jul 05 19:44:55 alarm kernel: vc4-drm soc:gpu: bound 3f400000.hvs (ops vc4_hvs_ops [vc4])
Jul 05 19:44:55 alarm kernel: vc4-drm soc:gpu: bound 3f206000.pixelvalve (ops vc4_crtc_ops [vc4])
Jul 05 19:44:55 alarm kernel: vc4-drm soc:gpu: bound 3f207000.pixelvalve (ops vc4_crtc_ops [vc4])
Jul 05 19:44:55 alarm kernel: vc4-drm soc:gpu: bound 3f807000.pixelvalve (ops vc4_crtc_ops [vc4])
Jul 05 19:44:55 alarm kernel: vc4-drm soc:gpu: bound 3fc00000.v3d (ops vc4_v3d_ops [vc4])
Jul 05 19:44:55 alarm kernel: checking generic (3eaf0000 10a800) vs hw (0 ffffffffffffffff)
Jul 05 19:44:55 alarm kernel: fb: switching to vc4drmfb from simple
Jul 05 19:44:55 alarm kernel: Console: switching to colour dummy device 80x25
Jul 05 19:44:55 alarm kernel: [drm] Initialized vc4 0.0.0 20140616 for soc:gpu on minor 0
Jul 05 19:44:55 alarm kernel: [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
Jul 05 19:44:55 alarm kernel: [drm] Driver supports precise vblank timestamp query.
Jul 05 19:44:55 alarm kernel: brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac43430-sdio for chip BCM43430/1
Jul 05 19:44:55 alarm kernel: brcmfmac mmc1:0001:1: Direct firmware load for brcm/brcmfmac43430-sdio.clm_blob failed with error -2
Jul 05 19:44:55 alarm kernel: brcmfmac: brcmf_c_process_clm_blob: no clm_blob available (err=-2), device may have limited channels available
Jul 05 19:44:55 alarm kernel: brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware: BCM43430/1 wl0: Oct 23 2017 03:55:53 version 7.45.98.38 (r674442 CY) FWID 01-e58d219f
Jul 05 19:44:55 alarm kernel: Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 170x48
Jul 05 19:44:55 alarm kernel: vc4-drm soc:gpu: fb0:  frame buffer device
Jul 05 19:44:56 alarm kernel: smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: hardware isn't capable of remote wakeup
Jul 05 19:44:56 alarm kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
Aug 22 05:03:30 alarm kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: command 0xfc18 tx timeout
Aug 22 05:03:30 alarm kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Aug 22 05:03:30 alarm kernel: smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: link up, 100Mbps, full-duplex, lpa 0xC1E1
Aug 22 05:03:38 alarm kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: failed to write update baudrate (-110)
Aug 22 05:03:38 alarm kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to set baudrate
Aug 22 05:03:38 alarm kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 94
Aug 22 05:03:38 alarm kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x2e
Aug 22 05:03:38 alarm kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43430A1
Aug 22 05:03:38 alarm kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43430A1 (001.002.009) build 0000
Aug 22 05:03:42 alarm kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43430A1 (001.002.009) build 0360
```

These journal logs were cut-off at 125 lines for the sake of space. Please let me know if more lines are needed. I also have tail outputs if needed.

**References**

Arch Linux ARMv8 hardware forum
https://archlinuxarm.org/forum/viewforum.php?f=67&sid=1b9abb0d1b51cbebef58c36a9a7c4e00

Digital Ocean journalctl tutorial
 https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-journalctl-to-view-and-manipulate-systemd-logs

freedesktop.org
https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journalctl.html

raspberrypi.org
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/

Comment: I assume you're aware that the [green LED is ***usually*** reserved for status or activity](https://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2013/02/raspberry-pi-status-leds-explained/)? Re your log entries: TL;DR. Could you briefly explain why you feel something is wrong?

Comment: @Seamus because it never blinked before. It blinks permanently, not just at bootup. Is it supposed to do this? Thanks.

Comment: not sure archLinux, especially the 64bit version will have this ... but ... is **heartbeat** in the output of `cat /sys/class/leds/led0/trigger` "selected"? i.e. `...timer oneshot [heartbeat] backlight gpio...` - oh, and I did have a similar issue when booting from USB - but that's not the case here I guess

Comment: I've deleted my comments to keep the "comment count" down as this triggers moving the comments to chat, and that can be inconvenient.

Comment: If I understand, you had no blinking lights with a previous install of ArchLinux?

Comment: @Seamus correct.

Comment: @JaromandaX I’ll give it a shot and add it to my question when I get to my desk. Thank you.